# Is there a way to gift Blizzard games using Battle.net?

Tags: battle.net

Can I buy a Blizzard game (Diablo III, Starcraft 2, or WoW suscriptions) for another Battle.net account?

I'm thinking about gifting a game, and I was wondering if there was a similar process as you can do it in Steam.

If it is possible, how is it done? Do I have to enter the recipients email address somewhere upon checkout and then he can redeem it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Update: Some in game items are unavailable for gifting.

It is currently possible to gift: World of Warcraft, WoW mounts/pets, StarCraft 1/2, Warcraft 3+expansion, Diablo 2+expansion and Diablo 3+expansion.

Pre-purchase of Overwatch and WoW:Legion seems to not be giftable.

From the [blizzard support page](https://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/battlenet-shop):

> **Gifting Items**
>
> *Heroes of the Storm in-game items, and Hearthstone in-game items are currently unavailable to gift.*
>
> To gift an item, click **Gift** instead of Buy Now on the item’s page.
>   During checkout, enter your friend’s email address. Once we process
>   your purchase, we’ll send a key code to their email address, and
>   you’ll receive a purchase receipt at your registered Battle.net email
>   address.
>
> **Note**: *Gift processing may take a few hours.* If you entered the wrong email address, you can find the key code for your purchase on
>   the Order History page once processing completes. You can copy this
>   code and send it to your friend.
>
> Your friend must have a Battle.net account to claim a game key. If you
>   gift them a World of Warcraft pet, mount, item, or game time, they
>   must have a World of Warcraft licence in good standing (not banned or
>   suspended) attached to their Battle.net account.
>
> **Note**: *You cannot gift Battle.net Balance, World of Warcraft character services, guild services, or subscriptions.*

Comment: This answer only concern World of Warcraft. There is no gift possibilities on Battle.net. This answer is not correct. It is for instance impossible to offer a pack of card in Hearthstone.

Comment: @B413 The answer was regarding all games in there store at the time. I have updated the answer to reflect the changes made by Blizzard since then

Comment: It's possible to [buy Overwatch as a gift](https://us.battle.net/shop/en/product/overwatch) by sending it to their email address. However, I don't see a way to directly send it to someone on your friends list

Answer (score -1):

I tried to send heart of the swarm to a friend. There is no way to do it on battle.net. You need to buy from another place and send the key.

Comment: That's probably because HoTS came out this week. They probably haven't implemented a gift option for it yet.

Answer (score -2):

the answer is no.  sure the FAQ on their website says you can do it, but you actually can't.  If you already own the game on your own account, there is no way to digitally buy the game through battle.net.  and if you don't own the game, there is no step during the checkout process to designate the item as a gift.  It's supposed to work, but in reality it doesn't.

Comment: Your answer is very different from the accepted one. Can you provide a source for this?

Answer (score -2):

Battle.net says that you can very ambiguously.  I haven't found any interface to send any game as a digital download gift that includes classic games, newer titles and games I do not own.  Nowhere in the purchase interface does the word "gift" appear.